# Polynomial Fields.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I am trying to find a polynomial in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ which is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ and has at least one linear factor over $\Bbb{R}$ and at least one irreducible quadratic factor over $\Bbb{R}$. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 7):

$$X^3-2{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: $X^3-2 = (X-\alpha)(X^2+\alpha x+\alpha^2)$, where $\alpha =\sqrt[3]{2}$.